# Visual Studio Code doesn't autocomplete JSX attributes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I'm using Visual Studio Code for a React project and have a lot of `.js` files which looks like:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

class Foobar extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        Foo
      </main>
    )
  }

}

export default Foobar
```

Autocompletion of React's own methods works fine (like adding `componentWill...` to the component), but I don't get any suggestions while typing JSX. Typing something like `onCli...` into `main` doesn't suggest `onClick`.

I've found some tutorials about typescript definitions, so I've installed:

```
"@types/react": "^16.0.36",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
```

But this doesn't do anything. Even if I rename my files from `.js` to `.jsx`, `.ts` or `.tsx` I don't get autocompletion on JSX attributes.

Is there anything that I've missed?

I also created a `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And added this to my VS Code config:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx"
},
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Comment: Are you under an assumption that this is supposed to be default behavior based on the autocomplete "intellisense" when overriding `React.Component`'s abstract methods?

Comment: I thought that VS Code would autocomplete at least normal HTML attributes like `name`, `type` and so on – like it does on normal `.html` files.

Comment: Understood -- did you check [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18427) ?

Comment: Yes, already checked this :(

Comment: Oooooh ... that's my problem too: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41123

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps, using vscode v1.63 will help.  It added this:

> #### JSX attribute completions
>
> When completing JSX attributes in JavaScript and TypeScript, VS Code
> will now automatically insert the attribute value:
>
> The behavior of these completions can be configured using
> `javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle` and
> `typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle`. Possible
> settings values are:
>
> `auto` — Infer the attribute style based on its type. Strings use
> `attr=""` while other types use `attr={}`.
> `braces` — Always use braces.
> `None` — Just complete the attribute name.

See [release notes: jsx attribute completions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#jsx-attribute-completions)

Comment: `javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle:auto` then i got single quotes. what i want is double quotes

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249577/7782258) the [November 2021 (version 1.63)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md) release includes [JSX attribute completions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#jsx-attribute-completions), simply update and restart VSCode, on menu bar **Code** > **Restart to Update** and open your settings **Code** >
[**Settings**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVzbz.png) to customize options from either quotes `attr=''` (default) to brackets `attr={}` or none, which simply completes the attribute. Or add this on your **settings.json** file:

```
"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "auto"
```

Comment: I have to ask if this adds anything substantive to my answer?

Comment: Hey @Mark sorry for the major delay. No not really, but I wanted to link your answer to google results, especially for [Grepper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Grepper.grepper) users, but it searches fenced code blocks not inline code. Hence my intro and the redundancy.