# JSX attribute suggestions not working in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Recently, the JSX attributes suggestion feature in VSCode stopped working. For example, when I write `<input auto/>` I no longer get suggestions like `autoFocus` for the attribute. I select `JavaScript React` at the bottom of the code editor, and in my `settings.json` file I have this line

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
  },
```

Otherwise, including JSX elements suggestions is working fine. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I've observed an issue where my version of VSCode fell out of date and I resolved some problems by upgrading to the latest version

Comment: Mine is up-to-date

Comment: Perhaps investigate this path (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65508013/vs-code-not-suggesting-jsx-attributes) or try disabling all of your extensions and restarting vscode

Comment: Yes, changing the file extension from .js to .jsx fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249577/836330 for jsx attribute values in v1.63 release notes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension from .js to .jsx