# Autocomplete for React components in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

is there a way for autocomplete react components like JSX tags , like this code below, I want VS code to autocomplete Header, Main and Footer Components and so on

```js
function App() {
    return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer/>
    </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Checkout this link for prop completion https://dev.to/maxbvrn/react-props-auto-complete-in-vs-code-2ana You should clarify whether you expect the tag names or their attributes to be auto completed

Comment: Do you mean the attributes for those tags or the tags themselves?  If the attributes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249577/836330 may help.

Comment: check answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to get JSX/HTML autocomplete in your React projects is to add this to your user settings or workspace settings (`<project-path>/.vscode/settings.json`):

```
      "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
      },
      "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

You may have to restart VS Code for the change to take effect.